# Does Devel::Cover work under mod_perl2 on Perl 5.10 for Windows?

Tags: windows, perl, code-coverage, mod-perl2

The mod_perl2 and Perl 5.10 two are playing nicely together, but I can't seem to find any positive information about [Devel::Cover](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Devel-Cover) working with mod_perl2 under Win32.  I'm currently using ActiveState's Perl 5.10, but I would be open to switching to Strawberry Perl if it meant this combination could work.

Also, Devel::Cover PPDs don't seem to be available for Perl 5.10 from ActiveState, Bribes, UWinnipeg, or Trouchelle, so if you have been able to get it to work, what steps did you go through to run a successful make?

Comment: Where have all the Perl developers gone?

Comment: http://perl.apache.org/docs/2.0/os/win32/install.html

Comment: Thanks Brad, but...what does that have to do with code coverage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems [more recent builds should now work on Windows](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/PJCJ/Devel-Cover-0.65/CHANGES) and are available from major repos for Perl 5.10.

But actually, when you go to use it, Apache shuts down just after loading, writing this to the error log:

```
Unfortunately, Devel::Cover does not yet work with threads.  I have done
some work in this area, but there is still more to be done.
```

Comment: Just as a general principle, always check the Changes and use the latest version before you ask these sorts of questions. A lot of people don't support older versions because their answer was to fix it and release a newer version. :)